# Unable to run terraform from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the below pipeline setup which uses terraform plugin to execute terraform. I can get till **"terraform plan"** and it fails with the following error "Failed to load Terraform configuration or plan". I'm able to initialize terraform but the next step is to execute **"terraform plan"**

I think the provider is not getting cached in the workspace.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
      stage ('Check Terraform Version') {
         steps {
            script {
            def tfhome = tool name: 'Terraform 0.11.13', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.terraform.TerraformInstallation'
            env.PATH = "${tfhome}:${env.PATH}"
          }
          sh 'terraform --version'
         }
      }
      stage ('Terraform Initialize & Plan'){
          steps {
            withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('AzureSPN')]){  
            sh '''
            terraform init
            terraform plan -input=false -var 'subscription_id='$AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -var 'client_id='$AZURE_CLIENT_ID -var 'client_secret='$AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET 'tenand_id='$AZURE_TENANT_ID
            '''
            }
          }
      }
      stage ('Terraform Apply') {
          steps { 
            sh '''
            terraform apply -input=false --auto-approve 
            '''
      }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure that this is your pipeline?
The `sh 'terraform --version'` outside of `steps` is weird..
The `terraform plan` lacks `-var` before `tenand_id=`.
I find it uncommon to quote the variable `variable=` parts.. have you tried it without that? Usually you would quote the values, if it all.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting and where it happens? The Jenkins log would be ideal.